# Issue Related to Hidden Field in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. i have added Hidden field on Master Page..

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenCriteria" Value="abcd"/>
```

When I try to get the value of Hidden field from Javascript :

```
alert(document.getElementById("ct100_hiddenCriteria").value);
```

I get the following value :

[image]

How to get real stored value ?

Comment: Is the page fully loaded/ hidden field is fully rendered prior to your js alert?

Answer (score 0):

```
var labelID  = '<%= hiddenCriteria.ClientID %>';
alert(labelID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ClientIDMode` to `Static` and it will output the ID of the control as *hiddenCriteria*

Makes it more JavaScript friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use client id in the javascript function as follows

```
 alert(document.getElementById('<%= hiddenCriteria.ClientID %>').value);
```

Or you can take benifit of ClientIDode to static as follow

```
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="hiddenCriteria" 
        Value="abcd"/>
```

and simply

```
alert(document.getElementById("hiddenCriteria").value);
```

For further reading

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature